# Usage of fast Hankel transform of scipy in python

Tags: python, scipy, fft

Despite some efforts I could not understand the usage of SciPy.fft.fht, the fast Hankel transform in Python. For example when I try to transform exp(-ar) it gives me some weird result. I also could not understand how to choose an appropriate offset. Here is my simple code.

```py
from scipy import fft
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu = 1.0 # Order of Bessel function
r = np.logspace(-7, 1, 128)  # Input evaluation points
dln = np.log(r[1]/r[0])      # Step size
offset = fft.fhtoffset(dln, initial=-6.*log(10), mu=mu)
k = np.exp(offset)/r[::-1]   # Output evaluation points

a = 0.5
f = np.exp(-a*r)             # This is what I want to transform
fk = k/np.sqrt((k**2+a**2)**3) # This is what I expect analytically (I looked it up from a table)
f_fht = fft.fht(f, dln, offset=offset, mu=mu) # This is the numerical result

plt.plot(k,fk,k,f_fht,'--')
plt.show()
```

It appears that f_fht does not agree with fk. I could not understand what goes wrong.
Can anyone explain how should I use fht with some examples? Thank you very much.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.fht.html

Comment: I saw that but it doesn't work when I try to transform exp(-ar).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Any idea about why fk and f_fht do not agree with each other in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a common one: The numerical FHT in SciPy is defined using an integral of `k dr`, while the definition of the mathematical Hankel transform uses `r dr` (see [scipy/scipy#19573](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/19573)).  To compute the Hankel transform that you expected, you need to multiply your input by `r` (to add the missing factor) and divide the output by `k` (to remove the extra factor).

```py
...
f_fht = fft.fht(f*r, dln, offset=offset, mu=mu)/k

plt.loglog(k,fk,k,f_fht,'--')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

As you see, this gets you closer, but there is significant aliasing of the result. We can bias the transform to obtain a better result:

```py
...
offset = fft.fhtoffset(dln, initial=-6.*np.log(10), mu=mu, bias=-1.5)
...
f_fht = fft.fht(f*r, dln, offset=offset, mu=mu, bias=-1.5)/k
...
```

[image: plot]

You probably still want to investigate why the agreement isn't perfect here, but I hope this demonstrates how SciPy's FHT works.